# Angular2 Error: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

i'm on the RC4 and i'm getting the error **There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"** because of my template :

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="actionType">Action Type</label>
        <select
            ngControl="actionType" 
      ===>  #actionType="ngForm" 
            id="actionType" 
            class="form-control" 
            required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let actionType of actionTypes" value="{{ actionType.label }}">
                {{ actionType.label }}
            </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
```

the boot.ts :

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms'; 

 import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from '@angular/http';
 import {provideRouter} from '@angular/router';

import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER} from './routes';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms(), APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

/// so here is my DropdownList :

```
<fieldset ngControlGroup="linkedProcess" >
                     <div ngControlGroup="Process" >
                         <label>Linked Process</label>
                          <div class="form-group">       
        <select 
            ngModel
            name="label" 
            #label="ngModel" 
            id="label" 
            class="form-control" required
            (change)="reloadProcesse(list.value)" 
            #list>
            <option value=""></option>
            <!--<option value=`{{ActionFormComponent.getFromString('GET'')}}`></option>-->                 
            <option *ngFor="let processus of linkedProcess?.processList?.list; let i = index" 
            value="{{ processus[i].Process.label}}">
                {{processus.Process.label}}
            </option>
        </select> 
        </div>
     </div>
```

//my component ts :

i was representing it in the old forms like this :

```
 categoryControlGroups:ControlGroup[] = [];
     categories:ControlArray = new ControlArray(this.categoryControlGroups);
```

and now i'm doing this :

```
categoryControlGroups:FormGroup[] = [];
     categories:FormArray = new FormArray(this.categoryControlGroups);
```

you think it's the cause of the prob ??

Comment: What version are you using? Did you boostrap the forms?

Comment: In some cases  #yourVariable="ngModel" is not placed at the right element

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Since [2.0.0.rc6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.x/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2016-08-31):

> **forms**: deprecated `provideForms()` and `disableDeprecatedForms()` functions have been removed. Please import the `FormsModule` or the `ReactiveFormsModule` from `@angular/forms` instead.

In short:

- If you use [*template-driven forms*, add `FormsModule`](https://angular.io/guide/forms#revise-appmodulets) to your `@NgModule`.
- If you use [model-driven forms, add `ReactiveFormsModule`](http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/#modeldrivenorreactiveforms) to your `@NgModule`.

So, **add to your `app.module.ts`** or equivalent:

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <== add the imports!
 
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,                               // <========== Add this line!
    ReactiveFormsModule                        // <========== Add this line!
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    // other components of yours
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Failing to have one of these modules can lead to errors, including the one you face:

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
>
> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'
>
> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"

If you're in doubt, [you can provide both](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.x/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2) the `FormsModule` and the `ReactiveFormsModule` together, but they are fully-functional separately. When you provide one of these modules, the default forms directives and providers from that module will be available to you app-wide.

---

### Old Forms using `ngControl`?

If you do have those modules at your `@NgModule`, perhaps you are using old directives, such as `ngControl`, which is a problem, because there's no `ngControl` in the new forms. It was replaced *more or less** by `ngModel`.

For instance, the equivalent to `<input ngControl="actionType">` is `<input ngModel name="actionType">`, so change that in your template.

Similarly, the export in controls is not `ngForm` anymore, it is now `ngModel`. So, in your case, replace `#actionType="ngForm"` with `#actionType="ngModel"`.

So the resulting template should be (`===>`s where changed):

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="actionType">Action Type</label>
    <select
  ===>  ngModel
  ===>  name="actionType" 
  ===>  #actionType="ngModel" 
        id="actionType" 
        class="form-control" 
        required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let actionType of actionTypes" value="{{ actionType.label }}">
            {{ actionType.label }}
        </option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

* More or less because not all functionality of `ngControl` was moved to `ngModel`. Some just were removed or are different now. An example is the `name` attribute, the very case you are having right now.

Comment: thank's for your answer, when i've change it i'm having the error **Cannot assign to a reference or variable** does it say something to you ??

Comment: Hmm.. it may be somewhere else. Do you have any `<input>` inside a `*ngFor`? (Probably won't work but try this and tell me if the message goes away: `<option *ngFor="let actionType of actionTypes; let i = index" value="{{ actionTypes[i].label }}">        {{ actionTypes[i].label }}     </option>`)

Comment: Do you have any <input> inside a `*ngFor`?

Comment: Try renaming the variable inside the `*ngFor` to something other than `actionType`, any good?

Comment: nope i don't but i have a select dropdown list that i'm iterating i don't know if it's the source of the error, please get a look at my updated question ...

Comment: Shouldn't, inside the `option *ngFor`, the `{{processus.Process.label}}`  be `{{processus[i].Process.label}}` (or the contrary, inside the `<option value`)? ..also, do you have in your code both selects you added to the question or just the second?

Comment: the two of them :(

Comment: About the `{{processus.Process.label}}`  or `{{processus[i].Process.label}}`, which one is correct?

Comment: without the i index, the first one : {{processus.Process.label}} was working pretty well on deprecated forms, and now even after trying your suggestion the error still here

Comment: `ngControlGroup`, in the new forms, was replaced by `ngModelGroup`, can you change it?

Comment: Look, your code works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ztRcGvD0CXnKklpkfH0U?p=preview  Can you change it so it is more like yours and fails?

Comment: i think the error come from my component not the template, i've updated my question to show you the definition :

Comment: adding the formsModule to my app module worked for me

Answer (score 63):

I faced the same issue. I had missed the forms module import tag in the app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
```

Comment: thanks for this, it worked fine but should it be app.module.ts not app.module.component.ts

Comment: This is not working for me even though I've already put the FormsModule import within my app.module

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem which was resolved by adding the FormsModule to the .spec.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and then adding the import to beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ YourComponent ]
  })
.compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are getting this instead:

> Error: Template parse errors:
>
> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "**ngModel**"

Which was [reported as a bug in github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12796), then likely it is not a bug since you might:

1. have a syntax error (e.g. an extra bracket: `[(ngModel)]]=`), OR
2. be **mixing Reactive forms directives**, such as `formControlName`, **with the `ngModel` directive**. This ["has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7"](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel), since this mixes both form strategies, making it:

> - seem like the actual `ngModel` directive is being used, but in fact it's an input/output property named `ngModel` on the reactive form directive that simply approximates (some of) its behavior. Specifically, it allows getting/setting the value and intercepting value events. However, **some of `ngModel`'s other features** - like delaying updates with`ngModel`Options or exporting the directive - **simply don't work** (...)
> - this pattern mixes template-driven and reactive forms strategies, which **we generally don't recommend because it doesn't take advantage of the full benefits of either strategy**. (...)
> - To update your code before v7, you'll want to **decide whether to stick with reactive form directives** (and get/set values using reactive forms patterns) **or switch over to template-driven directives**.

When you have an input like this:

```
<input formControlName="first" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

It will show a warning about mixed form strategies in the browser's console:

> It looks like you're using `ngModel` on the same form field as `formControlName`.

However, if you add the `ngModel` as a value in a reference variable, example:

```
<input formControlName="first" #firstIn="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

The error above is then triggered and no warning about strategy mixing is shown.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I realized I had not bound my component to a variable.

Changed

`<input #myComponent="ngModel" />`

to

`<input #myComponent="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="myvar" />`

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` to the `shared.module.ts` too:

(thanks to @Undrium for the [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43736565/285431)):

> ```
> import { NgModule }                                 from '@angular/core';
> import { CommonModule }                             from '@angular/common';
> import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }         from '@angular/forms';
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports:      [
>     CommonModule,
>     ReactiveFormsModule
>   ],
>   declarations: [],
>   exports: [
>     CommonModule,
>     FormsModule,
>     ReactiveFormsModule
>   ]
> })
> export class SharedModule { }
> ```

Comment: This solved my issue. Adding it just to app.module wasn't enough

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of use forms now in Angular2 is:

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" #username="ngModel" required />

        <label>Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" #password="ngModel" required />


    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-primary"/>

</form>
```

The old way doesn't works anymore

Answer (score 3):

Also realized this problem comes up when trying to combine reactive form and template form approaches. I had `#name="ngModel"` and `[formControl]="name"` on the same element. Removing either one fixed the issue. Also not that if you use `#name=ngModel` you should also have a property such as this `[(ngModel)]="name"` , otherwise, You will still get the errors. This applies to angular 6, 7 and 8 too.

Answer (score 1):

if `ngModule` is not working in input means try...remove double quotes around `ngModule`

like

```
<input #form="ngModel" [(ngModel)]......></input>
```

instead of above

```
<input #form=ngModel [(ngModel)]......></input> try this
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have both `ngModel and name` attributes in your select. Also Select is a form component and not the entire form so more logical declaration of local reference will be:-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="actionType">Action Type</label>
    <select
            ngControl="actionType" 
      ===>  #actionType="ngModel"
            ngModel    // You can go with 1 or 2 way binding as well
            name="actionType"
            id="actionType" 
            class="form-control" 
            required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let actionType of actionTypes" value="{{ actionType.label }}">
                {{ actionType.label }}
            </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
```

One more Important thing is make sure you import either `FormsModule` in the case of template driven approach or `ReactiveFormsModule` in the case of Reactive approach. Or you can import both which is also totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

my issue is make formcontrolname and ngModel

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem because I had a typo in my template near [(ngModel)]]. Extra bracket. Example:

```
<input id="descr" name="descr" type="text" required class="form-control width-half"
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': descr.dirty && !descr.valid}" maxlength="16" [(ngModel)]]="category.descr"
      [disabled]="isDescrReadOnly" #descr="ngModel">
```